# How can I access internal storage to list all pdf files in ListView

Tags: java, android

```
public ArrayList<String> GetFiles(String DirectoryPath) 
{
    ArrayList<String> MyFiles = new ArrayList<String>(); 
    File f = new File(DirectoryPath);
    f.mkdirs();
    File[] files = f.listFiles(); 
    if (files.length == 0) return null; 
    else {
        for (int i=0; i<files.length; i++)           MyFiles.add(files[i].getName());
    } 
    return MyFiles;
}
```

And then called this function passing `Enviroment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`

Now how can I do the same for internal storage?

Comment: You do not have access to the internal storage of the other application apart from your own. It is private to each application. External storage (device internal and SD card) are public and can be accessed by any application. To list PDF files, you need to enumerate the files present under the folder you want to consider, for example, cache and so on.

Comment: There is nothing called "Enviroment.getexternalstorage" Please edit your answer so we know what you actually passed into the method

Comment: @0X0nosugar Enviroment.getExternalStorageDirectory()

Answer (score 0):

```
public ArrayList<String> searchPdfInExternalStorage(File folder) {
        ArrayList<String> MyFiles = new ArrayList<String>(); 
        if (folder != null) {
            if (folder.listFiles() != null) {
                for (File file : folder.listFiles()) {
                    if (file.isFile()) {
                        //.pdf files
                        if (file.getName().contains(".pdf")) {
                            MyFiles.add(file.getPath());
                            Log.d("filePath-------", "" + file.getPath());
                        }
                    } else {
                        searchPdfInExternalStorage(file);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

get a list of pdf file from sd-card.you can load list on `ListView`

```
searchPdfInExternalStorage(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());
```

Comment: unable to recognise (fileDTO) please give any suggestion
And i wanna search pdf in internal storage for external storage im going good

Comment: Just comment that line